# How to extract webpage's title webpage from a url using gwt?

Tags: java, url, gwt

How to take metadata like title of a webpage from a url?
I need also to create a preview of the webpage, how to do?
Thanks

Comment: Using GWT? Isn't GWT a client-side GUI?

Comment: Are you asking how to go grab a page from some other site and then extract its title, or how to determine the title of the page the app is running in?

Comment: I'm asking how to go grab a page from some other site! I'm a beginner in the use of the framework, but I have sadly discovered GWT does not emulate the java.net package. have suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

To get the title of the current page, `Window.getTitle()`. To get the title of a remote page, you'd need to use something like [RequestBuilder](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/http/client/RequestBuilder.html).

Comment: I'm asking how to go grab a page from some other site! I'm a beginner in the use of the framework, but I have sadly discovered GWT does not emulate the java.net package. have suggestions?? Window.getTitle() return the title of the current page the app running in, right?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to display a page and get it's title client side is by using an iframe.  The issue with this is that it isn't really a preview.  It is a non-scalable window to the actual page. However access to the title is blocked for security reasons if the target page is in another domain.

```
final Frame f = new Frame("./cool.html");
f.addLoadHandler(new LoadHandler()
{
    @Override
    public void onLoad( LoadEvent event )
    {
        System.out.println(getTitle(f.getElement()));
    }

    private native String getTitle( Element frameElement )/*-{
        return frameElement.contentWindow.document.title;
    }-*/;
});
```

If you want to create a scalable preview or access a page on a different domain you will have to do it server side.